# How can two irrational numbers add to a rational number when each doesn't have an irrational part that can simply cancel out?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, irrational-numbers, rational-numbers

I think this is asking the same question as [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/937779/can-any-two-irrational-numbers-not-of-the-form-ma-and-n-a-be-added-to-produ) except that I don't quite understand the accepted answer.  For instance, I can produce(*) what I think is a counterexample:

$$\sqrt[3]{26+15\sqrt{3}} + \sqrt[3]{26-15\sqrt{3}}$$

I do not follow how, but it does seem to equal the integer `4`.  I do not see how this could be rewritten in the simple form in the linked question.

How can these two irrational numbers add up to a rational number?  I see there are two parts that could cancel out if they weren't under the cube root, but the fact that they are throws a monkey wrench into it with regards to me figuring it out. (I'm also curious if there are other numbers like this - I tried different symmetrical numbers under the cube roots and different roots besides cubed but I couldn't find any others.)

(*) By produce, I mean I encountered this counterexample, went searching for how it could be, and found the linked question and didn't see it mentioned there.

Comment: $$26+15\sqrt 3 = (2+\sqrt 3)^3,$$ and likewise for the $-$ case.

Comment: See [How to show that $\sqrt[3]{26+15\sqrt{3}}+\sqrt[3]{26-15\sqrt{3}} \in \mathbb{Z}$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1999767/how-to-show-that-sqrt32615-sqrt3-sqrt326-15-sqrt3-in-mathbbz)

Comment: Examples like this often come up with answers to the cubic formula.

Comment: @dxiv Thanks!  I tried search to see if there was a similar question, but I guess I didn't use the right syntax :-)

Comment: @Michael Bookmark [approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/) ;-)